# Inserting/Removing hex padding with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I am working with a database that encodes strings to hex and then pads the entire string with `0`'s.

Like this:

```
Origional String:           PartitionTest
JUST Hex-encoded Strring:   0x506172746974696f6e54657374
The output I see:           0x50006100720074006900740069006F006E005400650073007400
```

Is there anyway for me to remove the spaces and decode the final string back to text? AND, how would I then encode that text back to the padded string? I am already converting the string to hex with

```
SELECT 
    MASTER.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST('PartitionTest' AS VARBINARY))
```

but I don't have a clue how to pad that result out.

Thank you!

Comment: So you need to shove 00 after every 2 characters starting after the third? What a totally strange thing to do. You can do this with STUFF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
As input is varbinary, need to first convert it into varchar to use STUFF.

```
Declare @input varbinary(128) = 0x50006100720074006900740069006F006E005400650073007400
Declare @Temp as VARCHAR(350)
Set @Temp = CONVERT(VARCHAR(350), @input ,2)
declare @length int
set @length = len(@Temp)
select @length
declare @i int = 3


WHILE @i < @length/2+2
BEGIN
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, @i, 2, '')
    set @i = @i +2

END

select '0x' + @Temp
```

Comment: This works great to remove the padding, but what can I use to add it back? Thank you!

Comment: I guess I can do something like `CONVERT(VARCHAR(128),(SELECT [FLDVALUE] FROM TABLE WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE = 4),1)` and then convert back to VARBINARY when needed.

Comment: Also, I just tried modifying your answer with the following: SET @Temp = (SELECT [FLDVALUE] FROM TABLE WHERE RESOURCE_TYPE = 4) and for some reason the result from your answer is the letter that the first encoded letter (0x50) represents. The result is one item from a column marked as VARBINARY(128). Do I need to convert to another type before running it through the answer?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect! Would it be easy to modify this to reverse the process? i.e. 

`Input: 0x506172746974696F6E54657374`
`Output: 0x50006100720074006900740069006F006E005400650073007400`

Comment: @AlbertDorson, you might have to ask a new question for this